# How can I remove multiple segments from a video while keeping the audio?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video, video-encoding

I have tried the method described in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/682534/323079). It works well, except that the audio is missing. Can anyone suggest how to get both the video and audio into the output?

Example:

I have a 2min video shot on holiday, of a kangaroo. There are 2 sections of it (both about 6secs long) I want to extract (including the audio) into a single, short piece with just these 2 cute bits.

I know I can extract two separate bits, and join them, but the article mentioned above allowed me to do exactly what I wanted, but THERE IS NO AUDIO when you follow that method. I would like to use a similar single call of FFmpeg.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I remove multiple segments from a video using FFmpeg?](http://superuser.com/questions/681885/how-can-i-remove-multiple-segments-from-a-video-using-ffmpeg)

Comment: NO, this is not a duplicate. Its really an extension. How to get the audio as well as the video.

Comment: Please clarify: do you want to get one section from a longer file, and this smaller section should have both audio and video? Or is it something else? Please **edit your question** and add an example case to illustrate.

Comment: I have edited the original, as requested. I find it odd that some people point to my question as a duplicate, when I mentioned the referenced article in my question, and ask for help extending the functionality. That shows a lack of research by the respondents, not me.

Comment: The original answer by ptQa in the [referenced](http://superuser.com/questions/681885/how-can-i-remove-multiple-segments-from-a-video-using-ffmpeg) thread did not include the audio stream. See the  answer below to see the added audio stream and pads. The 2 step process is given only for matter of completeness.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here I am assuming that your original file is in `mp4` container, but the method should work for other containers as well.

**One step method**- (slightly more involved)
Also see the answer given by ptQa in the [referenced](https://superuser.com/questions/681885/how-can-i-remove-multiple-segments-from-a-video-using-ffmpeg) thread. But here is the same with audio added:

```bsh
ffmpeg -i inputfile.mp4 \
       -filter_complex "[0:v]trim=start=10:end=16,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a];
                        [0:v]trim=start=20:end=26,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[b];
                        [0:a]atrim=start=10:end=16,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[c];
                        [0:a]atrim=start=20:end=26,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[d];
                        [a][c][b][d]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[e][f]" \
       -map '[e]' -map '[f]' -strict -2 outputfile.mp4
```

This adds the audio stream and neccesary pads to get audio.

Provided for completeness:

**The Easy Way:** You could use the 2 step process which you are already aware of:

**First** Cut and extract the 2 pieces you want out of the full length video.
**Second** Join these 2 pieces together.

This should be the easy way out.

To cut a piece from say the third second to ninth second:

```bsh
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -ss 00:00:03 -to 00:00:09 -c:v copy -c:a copy part1.mp4
```

You can repeat the process for the second part. If it is from 10th second to 16th second:

```bsh
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -ss 00:00:10 -to 00:00:16 -c:v copy -c:a copy part2.mp4
```

Also, see [this](https://superuser.com/questions/377343/cut-part-from-video-file-from-start-position-to-end-position-with-ffmpeg) thread for more details.

Now you have 2 files which you can join. You can "concatenate" in at least 3 different ways. The way to do it without re-encoding is to do it through the demuxer option. Create a text file named (say) joinlist.txt with this content:

```bsh
file 'part1.mp4'
file 'part2.mp4'
```

To join the two files place the 2 movies and text (joinlist.txt) in the same folder and use this command:

```bsh
ffmpeg -f concat -i joinlist.txt -c copy joinedfile.mp4
```

Comment: Thank You, Rajib, that is exactly what I was looking for. I had tried a number of ways of selecting audio, but defining the 2 video bits and the 2 audio bits as output suitable for the next step eluded my various attempts (guesses!) at the syntax. Once again **Thank You**

Comment: If this solves your problem you might want to accept the answer by using the check mark.

Comment: Superb! Thanks Rajib! This was the easiest code that I found for ffmpeg related answers. It's clearly explained.

Comment: Excellent descriptions and a new way to join pieces of video using a single command. I'll definitely be using it.