# Ffmpeg Video Segment Remove

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I am removing multiple segment from a video using `ffmepg`
I am referring to this link -[How can I remove multiple segments from a video using FFmpeg?](https://superuser.com/questions/681885/how-can-i-remove-multiple-segments-from-a-video-using-ffmpeg)

I am executing below command:

```
String []complexCommand={"ffmpeg","-i","/sdcard/A.mp4","-filter_complex","[0:v]trim=duration=30[a];[0:v]trim=start=40:end=50,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[b];[a][b]concat[c];[0:v]trim=start=80,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[d];[c][d]concat[out1]","-map", "[out1]","-acodec","libmp3lame","-vcodec","mpeg4","-b:v","1024k","/sdcard/temp1.mp4"};
```

Executing this command creates a working Video but no audio can be heard. How do I enable audio. Or is there another way to remove multiple segments in `ffmpeg`.

Comment: Please show your actual, unscripted `ffmpeg` command and the complete console output.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://superuser.com/questions/722247/how-can-i-remove-multiple-segments-from-a-video-keeping-the-audio-using-ffmpeg/723519#723519). And always post your direct `ffmpeg` command like `ffmpeg -i infile...outfile` along with complete console output as well. No need to make command bold.

Answer (score 0):

I've updated that answer. If you want to have audio too, You have to do the same for audio streams. So the command should be:

```
ffmpeg -i utv.ts -filter_complex \
"[0:v]trim=duration=30[av];[0:a]atrim=duration=30[aa];\
 [0:v]trim=start=40:end=50,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[bv];\
 [0:a]atrim=start=40:end=50,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[ba];\
 [av][bv]concat[cv];[aa][ba]concat=v=0:a=1[ca];\
 [0:v]trim=start=80,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[dv];\
 [0:a]atrim=start=80,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[da];\
 [cv][dv]concat[outv];[ca][da]concat=v=0:a=1[outa]" -map [outv] -map [outa] out.ts
```