# Which program I can edit video (cut some scenes) without increasing the video's size

Tags: video, editing, cut

I have a video: Input.mp4 - length: 29 min 6 sec - size: 120 MB

I use Microsoft Movie Maker 2012 (Movie Maker is included in the Windows Essentials 2012 program suite), to cut some boring scenes and keep the cool scenes and I get the video: Output.mp4 - length: 15 min 22 sec - size: 155 MB.

Is there any program which I can use to cut and keep scenes without increasing the video size, and generate output video as fast as possible?

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe your question is for video SE site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) can do this quickly, with a command like this

First, create a text file, `segments.txt`, like this

```
file 'in.mp4'
inpoint 48.101
outpoint 67.459
file 'in.mp4'
inpoint 76.178
outpoint 86.399
file 'in.mp4'
inpoint 112.140
outpoint 125.031
```

then run,

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i segments.txt -c copy out_merged.mp4
```

Comment: Oh, this is what I intend to do. I just knew how to cut a video without re-encoding here [link](http://superuser.com/questions/377343/cut-part-from-video-file-from-start-position-to-end-position-with-ffmpeg) . 
I'll give it a try as soon as I've done my school assignment :)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.videoredo.com/en/index.htm

I use it all the time to edit my vidoes

Answer (score 0):

I use [Viosk](https://www.viosk.com/) video editing software to edit my videos and add some cute effects. It's my favourite tool that offers plenty of features.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use the Total Video Converter. It will help you to cut and merge the videos and also it provides the option to convert the videos,So that it makes the size of video in low memory.